# allow_url_fopen and file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, request, vk

Kind time of the day, dear users. I ran into the problem of the disabled allow_url_fopen parameter in the php.ini settings. I need to use the function "file_get_contents", but the host does not allow it. Roughly speaking:

```
$token = "SomeToken";
$request = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.get?out=0&offset=0&filtres=0&last_message_id=0&count=10&v=5.34&access_token=".$token."");
    echo $request;
    $result = json_decode($request);
    var_dump($result); // Outputed "NULL"
```

Is it possible to replace this whole thing with something that will not cause a forbidden function?

Comment: This is an English-speaking site. You probably want http://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make request using Curl function. 
If it is not working too, contact your hosting support and ask to open functions. Usually they can help.

Comment: I tried to query through the CURL, it passed and I got the object, but it's completely different and I can't interact with it.